# How to change SASS output style in order to make a new line after each ending curly brace?

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

The processed code looks like this:

```
.body {
  color: #eeeeee;
}
.someting {
    color: #dddddd;
}
```

I want it to be:

```
.body {
  color: #eeeeee;
}

.someting {
    color: #dddddd;
}
```

Is there such a possibility? Google can't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you could write a simple regex find-replace looking for `}`'s and replacing with `}\n`, and have Grunt execute that on your css (post-compilation from SASS).

This looks like it'd do the trick:

- https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-regex-replace

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can get is [`expanded`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_11). The extra line break won't be there when you're nesting but your example code would output exactly like you demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, you can go to `rubygems/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/to_css.rb` (or anywhere your to_css file is), and edit this:

`output("}" + trailer)` **to** `output("}\n" + trailer)`

And then remove this newline:

`trailer = "\n" if node.group_end`

It might have been an oversight when parsing the nesting, because the newline set on "trailer" applies to every other line (so you'd have double the lines without removing it if you don't nest anything).